# Как поменять картинку кнопки, при наведении на неё

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Как можно реализовать *смену картинки кнопки, при наведении* на неё?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from tkinter import *

class MyButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        Button.__init__(self, master=master, **kwargs)
        
        self.defaultImage = self["image"]
        self.bind("<Enter>", self.on_enter)
        self.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)

    def on_enter(self, e):
        self.Activ = PhotoImage(file='images\Help.png')
        self['image'] = self.Activ

    def on_leave(self, e):
        self['image'] = self.defaultImage

root = Tk()

photoImage = PhotoImage(file='images\Ok.png')
myButton = MyButton(root, image=photoImage)
myButton.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если мне нужно этот класс использовать для нескольких кнопок, и у всех разное название. 
`Photo1 = (file='Image\ProgrammingButton')
Photo2 = (file='Image\DesignButton')

But1 = (root, image=Photo1)
But2 = (root, image=Photo2)`

И мне надо чтобы при наведении картинки менялись так:

`Photo1 = (file='Image\ActiveProgrammingButton')
Photo2 = (file='Image\ActiveDesignButton')`

Comment: @zefercka   вы спросили:"Как можно реализовать смену картинки кнопки, при наведении на неё?".  Я вам предоставил вариант как это модно сделать. Примите решение по моему ответу. Если у вас есть другие проблемы, оформите новый вопрос, в котором приведите минимально-воспроизводимый пример и лучше расскажите, что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.